# What are the different URL parameters that Facebook will append to an Action URL? Values? Format?

Tags: facebook, action, facebook-opengraph

When a user clicks on an action that my application publishes to their wall I see the following URL parameters appended to the URL in my referral logs:

- fb_action_ids
- fb_action_types
- fb_source

Is there documentation that describes the format of these URL parameters?  If any of these parameters has a fixed value set what are the possible values? Are there additional parameters that are not listed here?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer - an explanation of the fb_source parameter.

Austin Haugen, a product manager on Facebook Platform, explains fb_source [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/397/) like this:

> When you use the ref parameter, we will also add a new fb_source parameter to our referrer URLs, which includes the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'other') where the click occurred and the story type ('oneline', 'multiline') concatenated with an underscore.We sanitize referrer URLs from Facebook to protect user privacy, but this parameter allows us to remove personally identifiable information while still exposing anonymous, yet useful data for developers interested in tracking and optimizing the performance of their Like buttons.

Which values can fb_source take?

On the [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) page on Facebook Developers, in the 'attributes' section, it says.

> fb_source - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'ticker', 'tickerdialog' or 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

and on the the [Send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) page, 'attributes' section it says:

> fb_source - the story type ('message', 'group', 'email') in which the click occurred.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've also seen fb_source with a "timeline_og" value.